# CakePHP / MySQL: find with a condition for model itself and an assigned model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Consider, we have users and the users have accounts (one-to-many). Now I am completely stuck at the following problem: we provide a `$query` and want to return all users:

- whose `fullname LIKE %$query%` OR
- whose `email LIKE %$query%` OR
- who have accounts, of which `organisation LIKE %$query%`

I already tried joins and containable behavior but no success. With joins we could achieve this, but the problem is, the data is not structured in the cake way (we get only one row pro match even if same user occurs multiple times). Resorting the data will not be OK because this controller must be very fast.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
$this->User->find(
    'all',
    array(
     'conditions' => array(
                      'OR' => array(
                               'User.fullname LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%',
                               'User.email LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%',
                               'Account.organisation LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%',
                              ),
                     ),
     'contain'    => 'Account',
    )
);
```

Using alias -

```
$qry = "select * from users as u, accounts as a where u.fullname like %$query% or u.emaillike %$query% or a.organisation like %$query%";
$results = $this->query($qry);
```

Comment: Exactly this will not work, returning 'unknown column Account.organisation'. Already tried. Cake seems to perform two individual queries when containing, so Account is not known for the "Users" query.

Comment: you can use custom queries instead then.

Comment: Yes but how, this is the question.

Comment: This will not return the data with the expected structure. I guess it's not even possible what I am trying to achieve. It's probably the simplest way to do it like you did and THEN to restructure the data with PHP (what I wanted to avoid but...). You'll get the green tick for your effort.

Comment: for this type of situation you have to do some customisations.. :)